Dataframe of raster images is taking too long
I am creating a DataFrame from the raster arrays of large raster images to train a Random Forest model, but the process of creating the DataFrame is taking too long due to the large size of the images.
# Get the full paths of the specified images
images_3m = [os.path.join(folder_path, f) for f in specific_images]

# Define arrays to store 3m image data
arrays_3m = []

# Loop through each 3m image
for image in images_3m:
    print(image)
    src = rasterio.open(image)
    profile = src.profile
    print(profile)

    # Read 3m image data
    array = src.read(1)
    
    # Convert all images to float64 to handle LST3m and SAVI30m
    array = array.astype(np.float64)
    
    # Handle nodata values (replace with 0)
    array[array == -3.4028230607370965e+38] = 0
    #array[array == -1.797693e+308] = 0
    
    # Store 3m image data in arrays list
    arrays_3m.append(array)
    
    # Display the 3m image
    plt.imshow(array, cmap='magma')
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()  
    src.close()

and then,
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

# Function to process a single image array into a list of pixel data
ny_3m = arrays_3m[0].shape[0]
nx_3m = arrays_3m[0].shape[1]

def process_array(i):
    values = []
    for y in range(ny_3m):
        for x in range(nx_3m):
            values.append([y, x, arrays_3m[i][y, x]])
    return np.array(values)

# Function to create DataFrame using threading
def create_dataframe_threading():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        # Parallelize processing each array
        results = list(executor.map(process_array, range(len(arrays_3m))))
    
    values_3m = np.array(results)
    print(values_3m.shape)

    # Creating the DataFrame
    df_3m = pd.DataFrame(values_3m[:, :, 2].T, columns=['NDVI', 'MSAVI', 'SAVI', 'IPVI', 'DVI'])
    df_3m["y"] = values_3m[0][:, 0]
    df_3m["x"] = values_3m[0][:, 1]
    
    # Filter out nodata values
    df_3m = df_3m[df_3m["NDVI"] != 0]
    
    return df_3m

# Call the function to create the DataFrame
df_3m = create_dataframe_threading()
print(df_3m)

Is there a faster way to convert these raster arrays into a DataFrame, or should I train the model directly without creating a DataFrame? Is that possible?
Waiting for any your valuable guidance.

Hello, what library do you use to train the random forest ? Casting a raster to a DataFrame shouldn't be necessary.

Thank you for your response. I am using scikit-learn library to train the random forest, particularly RandomForestRegressor from sklearn.ensemble.

So I believe you use the fit method of the RandomForestRegressor on with your training set. as mentioned by the documentation, you just have to pass your samples and the expected result as two array-like objects, meaning numpy arrays are perfectly fine (they usually are !)

Thank you for your comment. Now I am using numpy array to train the model. However,  I am having a problem with reshaping the prediction from the model, because, before training the model I am removing the no data values which are affecting the size I guess. When I am trying to create the raster image of the prediction from the model. I am getting error. Can you guide me the way forward. I searched for the basic codes but couldn't find any. I am a beginner.

When using the fit method you have to provide an input array of shape (n, k) and an ouput array, of shape (n,) (simple vector) or shape (n, p) depending on what output do you expect for each raster. Notice that both input and output have n rows. They need to correspond to each other -> the first row of the ouput should be the output for the first row of the input. Now, if you want to filter out NaN values from the input, get the indices of each row having a NaN and remove them from the input AND the output to keep the correspondences.

To get you started, to retrieve every row indices of an array that contains Nan values, given an array X, you can write : indices = np.argwhere(np.isnan(a).any(axis=1)), and then some conditional slicing (a.k.a a mask) to filter out unecessary rows.

Thank you for your response. I am following the steps.
